# How can I use Jenkins CI to save git repo files into a local folder?

Tags: php, apache, jenkins, ubuntu-18.04

All I need is for Jenkins to save the contents of my Git repository (which is a collection of php scripts) to a local folder on my machine.

The reason why this is more than just cloning the repository for a local save is because I need the files to be in /var/www/html specifically, as that is the only folder actionable by the Apache server that will be my web server.

I have Jenkins, the repository, periodic builds and everything else set up - just don't know what my "build" should be.

Is the best way to accomplish this setting the build to be a shell command?

I have tried setting the build action to be a shell command and moving the files individually with the 'mv' command.

### If this is the right approach, all I would need is confirmation. If there is a simpler way such as a built in Jenkins action to save to target, is there a Jenkins admin that could tell me what that action is?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a fine approach.

You could also archive the directory before you mv it to speed up the process. Either in a shell command in the build stage, or in the "Archive the Artifacts" post build action, and then mv the individual archive rather than moving the files individually.